# Collecting MongoDB delta data and pushing to kafka?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-kafka, flume, sqoop

We have a mongodb database which keep getting data from different sources, i want to keep pushing this data to kafka as producer in real time so that i can have spark kafka integration for my analytics. Let me know if anyone has done anything on this or if there is any probable solution to this. Flume doesnot support mongodb as source and sqoop is for RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kafka Connect for that:
https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

As per the above, there are at least 2 source connectors for mongodb available:

https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-mongodb

https://github.com/teambition/kafka-connect-mongo